# Request.GetOwinContext returns null within unit test - how do I test OWIN authentication within a unit test?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am currently trying to unit test the authentication for a new WebAPI project I am writing using OWIN to authenticate, and I am having problems with running it in a unit test context.

This is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRegister()
{
    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("localhost/myAPI"))
    using (AccountController ac = new AccountController()
        {
            Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
                (HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/myAPI/api/Account/Register")
        })
    {
        var result = ac.Register(new Models.RegisterBindingModel()
        {
            Email = "testemail@testemail.com",
            Password = "Pass@word1",
            ConfirmPassword = "Pass@word1"
        }).Result;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an `AggregateException` on getting the `.Result` with the following inner exception:

```
Result Message: 
Test method myAPI.Tests.Controllers.AccountControllerTest.TestRegister 
    threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.OwinContextExtensions
    .GetUserManager[TManager](IOwinContext context)
at myAPI.Controllers.AccountController.get_UserManager()
...
```

I have confirmed via debugging that my `Startup` method is being called, calling `ConfigurAuth`:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    app.UseWebApi(config);

    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single 
    //  instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>
        (ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for 
    //  the signed in user
    //  and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a 
    //  user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work - I can never get an OWIN context.  The test is failing on the following code:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = new ApplicationUser() 
       { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

This calls the `UserManager` property:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext()
           .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

It fails on:

```
return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

with a `NullReferenceException` - `Request.GetOwinContext` is returning `null`.

So my question is:  am I approaching this wrong?  Should I just be testing the JSON responses?  Or is there a good way to "internally" test OWIN authentication?

Comment: Apologies for the wall of text - I wanted to provide as much context as possible. :)

Comment: Pity none of the answers are actual answers instead of workarounds

Comment: Indeed.  I don't want to mock it, I want to actually test it.  Oh well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GetOwinContext calls context.GetOwinEnvironment();
which is

```
  private static IDictionary<string, object> GetOwinEnvironment(this HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return (IDictionary<string, object>) context.Items[HttpContextItemKeys.OwinEnvironmentKey];
    }
```

and HttpContextItemKeys.OwinEnvironmentKey is a constant "owin.Environment"
So if you are add that in your httpcontext's Items, it will work.

```
var request = new HttpRequest("", "http://google.com", "rUrl=http://www.google.com")
    {
        ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8  //UrlDecode needs this to be set
    };

    var ctx = new HttpContext(request, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));

    //Session need to be set
    var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
        new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
        HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
        SessionStateMode.InProc, false);
    //this adds aspnet session
    ctx.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
        null, CallingConventions.Standard,
        new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
        null)
        .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

    var data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"a", "b"} // fake whatever  you need here.
    };

    ctx.Items["owin.Environment"] = data;
```

Answer (score 10):

To make sure an OWIN context is available during your test (i.e., to fix the null reference exception when calling `Request.GetOwinContext()`) you'll need to install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin` NuGet package within your test project. Once that is installed you can use the `SetOwinContext` extension method on the request.

Example:

```
var controller = new MyController();
controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
    new Uri("api/data/validate", UriKind.Relative)
    );
controller.Request.SetOwinContext(new OwinContext());
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.owinhttprequestmessageextensions.setowincontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

That being said, I agree with the other answers for your specific use case -- provide an AppplicationUserManager instance or factory in the constructor. The `SetOwinContext` steps above are necessary if you need to directly interact with the context your test will use.

Comment: The trick was adding Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin.  Once I did that then it was easy peasy.

Comment: controller.Request is readonly on my computer. Are there any versions of .net Mvc where it is not?

Comment: The answer above applies to Web API controllers (controllers inheriting from `ApiController`. MVC controllers (inheriting from `Controller`) in ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 have a readonly `.Request` property. Further, `ControllerBase.Request` is readonly in ASP.NET Core 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass in the UserManager in the constructor of the AccountController, so it doesn't try to find it in the owinContext.  The default constructor is not unit test friendly.

Comment: How do you find the UserManager?  How do you find this in the context of the unit test?

Comment: You can just new one up (mock or real) for a unit test

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is to inject AccountController with a user manager factory. That way you can easily swap an instance of the user manager that is used in test. Your default factory can take the request in the constructor to continue providing per request instances of the user manager. Your test factory simply returns an instance of the user manager you want to supply your tests with, I usually go for one that takes a stubbed out instance of a IUserStore so there is no hard dependency on a back end used for storing identity information.

Factory interface and class:

```
public interface IUserManagerFactory<TUser>
    where TUser : class, global::Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>
{
    UserManager<TUser> Create();
}


public class UserManagerFactory : IUserManagerFactory<AppUser>
{
    private HttpRequestMessage request;

    public UserManagerFactory(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        this.request = request;
    }

    public UserManager<AppUser, string> Create()
    {
        return request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    }
}
```

AccountController:

```
public AccountController(IUserManagerFactory<AppUser> userManagerFactory)
{
    this.userManagerFactory = userManagerFactory;
}

private UserManager<AppUser> userManager;

public UserManager<AppUser> UserManager
{
    get
    {
        if (this.userManager == null)
        {
            this.userManager = this.userManagerFactory.Create(); 
        }

        return this.userManager;
    }
}
```

Test factory:

```
public class TestUserManagerFactory : IUserManagerFactory<AppUser>
{
    private IUserStore<AppUser> userStore;

    public TestUserManagerFactory()
    {
        this.userStore = new MockUserStore();
    }

    public UserManager<AppUser> Create()
    { 
        return new UserManager<AppUser>(new MockUserStore());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"a", "b"} // fake whatever  you need here.
};

ctx.Items["owin.Environment"] = data;
```

Used this piece of code and added to the HttpContext instead of ctx and unit test worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here helped, but didn't quite get me there all the way, here's a full example:

```
var userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<User>>();
var appUserMgrMock = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>(userStore.Object);

var owin = new OwinContext();
owin.Set(appUserMgrMock.Object);

HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://test.com", null), new HttpResponse(null));
HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] = owin.Environment;
```

Remember to install all required nuget packages!